# Integration of ns-2.35 and EvalVid 2.7 : Problem with tcl

Tags: compiling, make, tcl

I use ubuntu 14.04 and i am trying to integrate evalvid 2.7 and ns2.35. 
I added necessary files like: myevalvid.cc, myudp.cc, myudp.h, myevalvid_sink.cc, myevalvid_sink.h . And inside the Makefile.in i have put myevalvid/myudp.o, myevalvid/myevalvid_sink.o and myevalvid/myevalvid.o in the OBJ_CC list.

But the problem is, when i enter the ./configure command, i get this error from the console referring to the tcl program:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define EXTENSIONS... yes
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for dcgettext in -lintl... no
checking for getnodebyname in -ldnet_stub... no
checking that g++ can handle -O2... yes
checking if C++ libraries work without any namespace... no
checking if C++ libraries work with namespace std... yes
checking if STL works without any namespace... no
checking if STL works with namespace std... yes
checking should use STL... yes
checking for tcl.h... -I../include
checking for tclInt.h... -I../include
checking for libtcl8.6... no
checking for init.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5
checking for http.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.5/http1.0
checking Tcl http.tcl library... yes
checking for tclsh8.6.1... no
checking for tclsh8.6... /usr/bin/tclsh8.6
configure: error: Installation of tcl seems incomplete or can't be found automatically.

Please correct the problem by telling configure where tcl is
using the argument --with-tcl=/path/to/package
(perhaps after installing it),
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-tcl=no.
```

Can anyone help me fix this please. I really need to make it work, to continue with the project i am working on.

Comment: Post this in StackOverflow. They specialize on programming questions. You will get a quick answer.

Comment: At a guess, you need to install the `tcl-dev` package

Comment: I have installed the tcl-dev but it didn't work.

Comment: I will also post it in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`